# TypeScript, infer keys from object

Tags: typescript

I have an object that contains all the keys that should be valid in a new object I need to make with some modifications to the values of said keys.

Example:

```
// This object contains all the keys i want to use in a different object below -> "one" and "two".
const myObject: { [id: string]: string } = {
    one: 'foo',
    two: 'bar',
};
```

This is how I've tried to extract the keys:

```
type MyType = {
  [T in keyof typeof myObject]: {
    bar: string
  };
}
```

If I hover over `MyType` in VSCode i see this:

```
type MyType = {
    [x: string]: {
        bar: string;
    };
}
```

This is obviously wrong, as it should not accept any string, but the set of keys defined in `myObject`.

And this is how I've tried to use the new type:

```
const test: MyType = {
  one: {
    bar: 'foo'
  },
  two: {
    bar: 'string'
  },
  shouldNotBeValid: {
    bar: 'foo'
  }
}
```

The key "shouldNotBeValid" shouldn't be allowed, but it still passes. However, if I remove the typing of `myObject`, so it's like this:

```
const myObject = {
    one: 'foo',
    two: 'bar',
};
```

and then hover over `MyType` I get this which is correct:

```
type MyType = {
    one: {
        bar: string;
    };
    two: {
        bar: string;
    };
}
```

Is it possible to express `MyType` how I want, and still be able to keep typing of `myObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a generic function to create the `myObject` variable. The generic function will constrain the type to `Record<string, string>` but also return the original type of the object.

```
const myObject = createMyObject({
    one: 'foo',
    two: 'bar',
})

function createMyObject<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T) {
  return obj
}

type MyType = {
  [T in keyof typeof myObject]: {
    bar: string
  };
}
// type MyType = {
//     one: {
//         bar: string;
//     };
//     two: {
//         bar: string;
//     };
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8NgBOGAhlBgLLLpZQAUA3gFAwszgYBcMA5AGYghuAGmasoAdxBduKYgWGMAvgEpGjXgFcw2AJbh8RUhSqZsAHgAqMDAA8yYACYQYAJSwgCDs9AI6wAcyEYHz9-AD4w2hB0LgtlGCYWIigNAjA2dCU1KAQABwwYSgs8grxEmABtKz8YAGsMBBBeGBz8pvgTGgBdLnKWWQIuEIDRRQBuLIB6SZaSwoRi-JgyxmnWFnZe1Zn19YGhqF8AibX18e3diSkEi93WfeDD0JOd1nO1xSA)